# JSON Path Filter Expression SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I have below JSON. I was trying to construct a query to fetch the FirstName, LastName, Iphone Number and Home Number. I am trying to use JSON Path filter expression. Its not working for me.

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

Query used

```
DECLARE @jsonInfo NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @jsonInfo=N'{  

  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]

 }' 
 SELECT
 JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo,'$.firstName') AS FirstName,
 JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo,'$.lastName') AS LastName

 --JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo,'$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=="iPhone")].number') AS IPhoneNumber,
 --JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo,'$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=="home")].number') AS HomeNumber
```

Regards
Amirtharaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to parse this JSON is with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema. `phoneNumbers` is a JSON array, so you need an additional `OPENSJON()` call.

```
 SELECT 
    j1.firtstName, j1.lastName, j1.streetAddress, j1.city, j1.postalCode,
    j2.*
 FROM OPENJSON(@jsonInfo) WITH (
    firtstName varchar(100) '$.firstName',
    lastName varchar(100) '$.lastName',
    streetAddress varchar(100) '$.address.streetAddress',
    city varchar(100) '$.address.city',
    postalCode varchar(100) '$.address.postalCode',
    phoneNumbers nvarchar(max) '$.phoneNumbers' AS JSON 
 ) j1
 CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
       MAX(CASE WHEN [type] = 'iPhone' THEN [number] END) AS iPhone,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [type] = 'home' THEN [number] END) AS home
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.phoneNumbers) WITH (
       type varchar(10) '$.type',
       number varchar(20) '$.number'
    ) 
 ) j2
```

Result:

```
firtstName  lastName    streetAddress   city    postalCode  iPhone          ome
John        doe         naist street    Nara    630-0192    0123-4567-8888  0123-4567-8910
```

Of course, you can extract each phone number from `$.phoneNumbers` JSON array using `$.phoneNumbers[x].number` as `path` expression (`x` is zero-based index):

```
SELECT 
    j1.firtstName, j1.lastName, j1.streetAddress, j1.city, j1.postalCode,
    j1.number1, j1.number2
 FROM OPENJSON(@jsonInfo) WITH (
    firtstName varchar(100) '$.firstName',
    lastName varchar(100) '$.lastName',
    streetAddress varchar(100) '$.address.streetAddress',
    city varchar(100) '$.address.city',
    postalCode varchar(100) '$.address.postalCode',
    number1 varchar(100) '$.phoneNumbers[0].number',
    number2 varchar(100) '$.phoneNumbers[1].number'
) j1
```

Comment: The Output must be single Record . Not multiple Records


FirstName  LastName Iphone Home
John doe 0123-4567-8888 0123-4567-8910

Comment: Thanks, for now. I will analyse the Query and let you know if any issues.

Comment: I agree your Cross Apply Solution. Zero based index will not work because in my real examples in Project we have various types and possible they will not come in Fixed postion.

Comment: I would say your answer is brilliant. Tested for multiple records from database.